# Override find_by method with and without bang

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4. Here's my code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_uid(uid)
    where("BINARY uid = ?", uid).first
  end

  def self.find_by_uid!(uid)
    where("BINARY uid = ?", uid).first!
  end
end
```

`find_by_uid!` is used in controller to raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when record is not found, and `find_by_uid` is used internally (so that no exception is raised).

Is there a better way to code this?

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Looks fine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Any dryer way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dry the methods by creating a scope:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :by_uid, ->(uid) { where("BINARY uid = ?", uid) }

  def self.find_by_uid(uid)
    by_uid(uid).first
  end

  def self.find_by_uid!(uid)
    by_uid(uid).first!
  end
end
```